# How to get the index value of v-for as a argument of a function of computed property in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to take the index value of v-for (which is in path tag) as a parameter in a function `stateData(index)` defined in computed property in Vue. I have tried to do this by `v-model="stateData[index]"` but the console box is showing an error that path tag is not supporting v-model(you can see by running the snippet).

Does anyone have any idea?

```js
  var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data(){
        return {
                statesJson: null,
                }
            },
        methods:{
          axiosCall() {
               axios.all([axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/India.json')])
              .then(axios.spread((user1) => (
               this.statesJson=user1.data
      )))
              .catch(error => {
               console.log(error)
      })
    },    
        },
        computed: {
        // Typical projection for showing all states scaled and positioned appropriately
        projection () {
          return d3.geoMercator().scale(900).translate([-1030, 700])
        },

        // Function for converting GPS coordinates into path coordinates
        pathGenerator () {
          return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection)
        },
            // Combine the states GeoJSON with a rank-based gradient
        stateData (index) {
          return this.statesJson ? this.statesJson.features.map(feature => {
            return {
              feature
            }
          }):[]
        }
       },
      created:function(index){
            this.axiosCall();
          },
     })
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
            <div>
                <svg id="svg" ref="svg" height="600" width="510">
                    <path class="bar" v-for="(state, index) in stateData" v-model="stateData[index]"  :d="pathGenerator(state.feature)" :style="{
           stroke: 'darkslategray'
         }">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure you are really aware of what you try to do. You have a v-for loop over a computed property, and than you want to access the items in the array the computed property outputs? Why would you need the index to get the item when you already get the item `state` passed for that use?

Comment: Shouldn't your `pathGenerator` be in `methods` instead of `computed`? In that case you can pass the `state` our of the v-for into your `pathGenerator` using `state.feature`

Comment: @MaartenVeerman actually I just want to use the `Id` of `stateStats:[{"State":"Rajasthan","Id":"1"},{"State":"Punjab","Id":"2"},.........................................]` data property in `stateData()` computed property. And I want that as v-for iterates `Id` of `stateStats` property should also get the iterating values in 'stateData()` function.

Answer (score 1):

See below an example on how to use objects in for loops. I've simplified your code, I don't think there is any need to use the index, as you can see below.

I've removed the `statesData` function, since it basically maps an array to an array, so you can simplify that by accessing the `statesJson.features` object immediately on the `v-for`.

I than use the `state` from the `v-for` as input in a new `calcFill` function. Inside that function, which is in the `methods` propery of your Vue component, you can calculate the gradient by rank. Using the `state` object, we can now simply access `state.rank` immediately, no need for using the `index`.

This is just an example showing that sometimes it's better to keep objects as they are and work with those object directly as method parameters.

When you run the snippet, you see each state is now color coded by it's rank.

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data(){
        return {
                statesJson: null,
                }
            },
        methods:{
          axiosCall() {
               axios.all([axios.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smlab-niser/CRiAPGraph/master/India.json')])
              .then(axios.spread((user1) => (
                this.statesJson=user1.data
               )))
              .catch(error => {
               console.log(error)
              })
          },
          calcFill(state) { // Here you can do your rank based gradient
            let l = this.statesJson.features.length
            let rank = state.rank
            let num = (rank / l) * 255 // Calculate color code
            return 'rgb(' + num + ', ' + num + ', ' + num + ')'
          }
        },
        computed: {
          // Typical projection for showing all states scaled and positioned appropriately
          projection () {
            return d3.geoMercator().scale(900).translate([-1030, 700])
          },

          // Function for converting GPS coordinates into path coordinates
          pathGenerator () {
            return d3.geoPath().projection(this.projection)
          }
       },
      created:function(index){
            this.axiosCall();
          },
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
            <!-- Only show if statesJson is loaded -->
            <div v-if="statesJson">
                <svg id="svg" ref="svg" height="600" width="510">
                    <!-- Loop directly on statesJson, keeping the object -->
                    <path class="bar" v-for="(state, index) in statesJson.features"  :d="pathGenerator(state)" :style="{
           stroke: 'darkslategray', fill: calcFill(state)
         }">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Thank You but I just want to color the map according some other data, that's why I asked you to color it according to the `Id` of `stateStats` in the previous comment. I don't want to use the rank of Json file

Comment: I the calcFill function I access the rank on the state object. You can just as well access the ID

Comment: actually it is the main problem that how to access the Ids one by one with the v-for. what should I put in the square bracket of `this.stateStats[........]['Id']`.

Comment: When I look at the data in `features`, I don't see an `Id`, I only see `ID_1`. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean the `index` in the array, e.g. the position of the element in the array? But that is right here: `v-for="(state, index) in statesJson.features"` The `index` is given to you by the `v-for` loop itself.